# Keep adding two numbers until the input is not a double type

Tags: java, types, calculator

I am trying to make a simple calculator program where a user enters two values, the method add() is called from the Operations class and the values are added and the result is displayed. And then I am using a do while loop in which the user keeps entering values which are added to the last total and the result is displayed. It has to keep running unless the user enters some input which is not of the type double.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the first number: ");
        double number = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter the second number: ");
        double number2 = input.nextDouble();

        double total = Operations.add(number, number2);
        System.out.println(total);

        System.out.println("Enter the number again: );
        number2 = input.nextDouble();

        do {
            total = Operations.add(total, number2);
            System.out.println(total);
            System.out.println("Enter the number again: ");
            number2 = input.nextDouble();
        } while (input.hasNextDouble());

        System.out.println("Exit.");
    }
}
```

And here is the Operations class

```
public class Operations {
    public static double add(double n1, double n2) {
        return n1 + n2;
    }
}
```

It adds the first two values, and displays the result. Then it asks for the value again, user inputs, and it displays the result. But from here on there is a problem somewhere which I have tried so hard to figure out but couldn't do so. So please look over my code and tell me where the problem is. Its something in the do while loop which I am doing wrong.

**Output:**

Enter the first number:

5

Enter the second number:

2

7.0

Enter the number again:

1

8.0

Enter the number again please:

2

**Here the program is running but does nothing when I press 2. If for example I press 6 again, it will still add 2 (which I entered before) to the total and display that**

6

10.0

Enter the number again please:

Comment: "But from here on there is a problem somewhere".  What's the problem?  Do you get an exception?  You're calling `input.nextInt()` on number2, which is a double.

Comment: no from there on when I enter a value, nothing happens (the program keeps running). When I enter again, then its accepted, added to the total and displayed. But when I enter another value, the result is incorrect.

Comment: just changed that to nextDouble() but the result is same

Comment: Can you give an example sequence of inputs and outputs?  You've got more `nextInt()` calls before and inside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue lies with the order in which things are occurring.  You want to prompt and input at the beginning of the do-while:

```
    do {
      System.out.println("Enter the number again: ");
      number2 = input.nextDouble();
      total = Operations.add(total, number2);
      System.out.println(total);
    } while (input.hasNextDouble());
```

This makes the first re-prompt and re-input redundant, so your final class looks like:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Enter the first number: ");
      double number = input.nextDouble();

      System.out.println("Enter the second number: ");
      double number2 = input.nextDouble();

      double total = Operations.add(number, number2);
      System.out.println(total);

      do {
        System.out.println("Enter the number again: ");
        number2 = input.nextDouble();
        total = Operations.add(total, number2);
        System.out.println(total);
      } while (input.hasNextDouble());

      System.out.println("Exit.");
    }
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to edit the upper portion of do while loop. Thank you its working now.